# Change type of line in legend (ggplot2) in figure with geom_step

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
t <- c(1,1,2,2,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,6,6,7,8,8,8,8,9,10,10,11,11,11,12,12,13,15,16,17,17,19,
       20,22,22,23,23,25,32,32,34,35)
status <-c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0)
grupo <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0)
sex <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
data<- data.frame(t,status,grupo, sex)

# Fit a Cox model 
library(survival)
fit <- coxph(Surv(t,status) ~ grupo+sex, data=data, method='breslow')

# Predict Survival
datosnuevos <- data.frame(grupo=c(0,0,1,1), sex=c(0,1,0,1))  
curva <- survfit(fit, newdata = datosnuevos, conf.type = "log-log")
df<- data.frame(time=curva$time, TtoFemale=curva$surv[,1], TtoMale=curva$surv[,2],
                PboFemale=curva$surv[,3], PboMale=curva$surv[,4])

# log minus log (survival)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot()+
  geom_step(aes(time, log(-log(TtoFemale)), col='TTo0_Female0'), lty=2, data=df)+
  geom_step(aes(time, log(-log(TtoMale)), col='TTo0_Male1'),lty=2, data=df)+
  geom_step(aes(time, log(-log(PboFemale)), col='Pbo1_Female0'), data=df)+
  geom_step(aes(time, log(-log(PboMale)), col='Pbo1_Male1'), data=df)+
  labs(color= 'TRT-Sex', x = "time", y = "log(-log Survival)", title = "")+
  scale_color_manual(name = "TRT-Sex", values = c("TTo0_Female0" = "pink", "TTo0_Male1" = "blue",
                    "Pbo1_Female0" = "pink", "Pbo1_Male1" = "blue"))+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(legend.position = "right", legend.direction = "vertical") +
  theme(legend.title = element_text(family = "Courier", color = "black", size = 12,  face = 1))+
  theme(legend.text = element_text (size = 10)) +
  scale_linetype_manual(name = "TRT-Sex", values=c(2,2,1,1))
```

[image]

How can I modify the two first lines in the legend (must be 'dotted line')
I have tried it with --  scale_linetype_manual(name = "TRT-Sex", values=c(2,2,1,1)) --- but It doesn't work...
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use

`guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype = c(2,2,1,1))))`

```r
t <- c(1,1,2,2,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,6,6,7,8,8,8,8,9,10,10,11,11,11,12,12,13,15,16,17,17,19,
       20,22,22,23,23,25,32,32,34,35)
status <-c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0)
grupo <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0)
sex <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
data<- data.frame(t,status,grupo, sex)

# Fit a Cox model 
library(survival)

fit <- coxph(Surv(t,status) ~ grupo+sex, data=data, method='breslow')

# Predict Survival
datosnuevos <- data.frame(grupo=c(0,0,1,1), sex=c(0,1,0,1))  
curva <- survfit(fit, newdata = datosnuevos, conf.type = "log-log")
df<- data.frame(time=curva$time, TtoFemale=curva$surv[,1], TtoMale=curva$surv[,2],
                PboFemale=curva$surv[,3], PboMale=curva$surv[,4])

# log minus log (survival)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot()+
  geom_step(aes(time, log(-log(TtoFemale)), col='TTo0_Female0'), lty=2, data=df)+
  geom_step(aes(time, log(-log(TtoMale)), col='TTo0_Male1'),lty=2, data=df)+
  geom_step(aes(time, log(-log(PboFemale)), col='Pbo1_Female0'), data=df)+
  geom_step(aes(time, log(-log(PboMale)), col='Pbo1_Male1'), data=df)+
  labs(color= 'TRT-Sex', x = "time", y = "log(-log Survival)", title = "")+
  scale_color_manual(name = "TRT-Sex", values = c("TTo0_Female0" = "pink", 
                                                  "TTo0_Male1" = "blue",
                                                  "Pbo1_Female0" = "pink", 
                                                  "Pbo1_Male1" = "blue"))+
  
  scale_linetype_manual(name = "TRT-Sex", values=c(2,2,1,1))+
  #new
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype = c(2,2,1,1))))+
  #
  theme_classic()+
  theme(legend.position = "right", 
        legend.direction = "vertical",
        legend.title = element_text(family = "Courier", color = "black", size = 12,  face = 1),
        legend.text = element_text (size = 10))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Ok. But I have tried and It doesn't work ...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand on the first time. Now I think it's right. I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  It work's perfectly and it's easier for me than the other answer. But the other is also useful, to put in the same line (geom_step) the four levels...

Answer (score 2):

This type of problems generally has to do with reshaping the data. The format should be the long format and the data is in wide format. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format) on how to reshape the data from wide to long format.
Then only one call to `geom_step` will plot all 4 lines and the legend automatically draws the lines with the same type as the graph since it inherits the `linetype` aesthetic.

```r
library(ggplot2)

df |>
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = -time, names_to = "TRT-Sex") |> 
  ggplot(aes(time, log(-log(value)))) +
  geom_step(aes(color = `TRT-Sex`, linetype = `TRT-Sex`), size = 1) +
  labs(color = "TRT-Sex", x = "time", y = "log(-log Survival)", title = "")+
  scale_color_manual(name = "TRT-Sex", 
                     values = c(TtoFemale = "pink", TtoMale = "blue",
                                PboFemale = "pink", PboMale = "blue")) +
  scale_linetype_manual(name = "TRT-Sex", 
                        values = c(TtoFemale = "dashed", TtoMale = "dashed",
                                   PboFemale = "solid", PboMale = "solid")) +
  theme_classic(base_size = 16) +
  theme(legend.position = "right", legend.direction = "vertical",
        #legend.title = element_text(family = "Courier", color = "black", size = 12,  face = 1),
        legend.text = element_text (size = 10),
        legend.key.width = unit(2, "line"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>