# ggplot Race Results

Tags: r, ggplot2

Practicing my ggplot and challenging myself.  I have an F1 data set I'm working from (found on Github if interested).  I am attempting to graph each driver's position per lap for the entire race.  The x axis is the lap count, that's easy.  The y axis is the challenge.  It needs to be the position for each lap for each racer.  I can accomplish this for a single lap, but cannot figure out how to stack the y-axis with both position and racer.

Here is my code for the single racer:

```
 f1laps %>%
 filter(raceId == 1074, code == "HAM") %>%
  ggplot(aes(lap, position))+
   geom_line()
```

This produces the following result:

[image]

My goal is to then stack all 20 racers and show each racer's position per lap (color coded and labeled...).

I'm NOT looking for somebody to write this for me.  Instead, I'm looking for guidance.  Are there arguments I need to research/look into or other commands that allow me to accomplish this?  Thank you.

Comment: This type of problems generally has to do with reshaping the data. The format should be in long format. See examples of line plots with `ggplot`, for instance, [here 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76644769/how-to-plot-points-across-time-when-the-years-are-different-columns), [here 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74018631/change-type-of-line-in-legend-ggplot2-in-figure-with-geom-step), [here 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75499124/how-do-i-make-my-plot-from-r-look-like-the-one-i-have-on-python).

Comment: If ‘code’ is a racer, you could remove that from the filter and instead include something like ‘color = code’ inside the ‘aes()’ part. I suggest you read this chapter for more:  https://r4ds.had.co.nz/data-visualisation.html

Comment: Thanks for the chapter, I'll look it over.  Indeed the code is the abbreviation of the driver's name:  HAM = Hamilton.

I started with color = code and it just created a mess of lines, very strange result and no color differentiation.  I suspect I have to layer geom's to do this correctly.

Comment: `geom_line()` or its brother `geom_path()` require a key to differentiate between different drivers (and races). When you use colors, you implicitly provide such a key, but I think it is safer to explicitly state aes(..., group = key). What you see as a mess is typically ggplot connecting last and first points. Thus, there is a good chance that ggplot cannot resolve the groups. Be mindful, if you plot multiple races, the key would be the combination of driver+raceId. If things do not look the way you hoped, start with a `geom_point()` and then move to `geom_line()`.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out... it was not properly grouped.

```
  f1laps %>%
    filter(raceId == 1075) %>%
    group_by(code) %>%
    ggplot(aes(lap, position, color = code))+
     geom_line() + 
     xlim(0, max(f1laps$lap)) +
     ylim(0, max(f1laps$position))
```

Now it's a matter of cleaing up the axes.  Setting the scale(x) and somehow getting the y scale to align the driver code next to the first lap.

```
 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgjsy.png
```